# flutter doesn't see images from assets/images

Tags: flutter, dart, builder

**I'm using spider to implement a dynamic photo upload builder, but for some reason Dart doesn't see photos from the assets/images folder**

[image: my project structure]

**below are all the working files of the project that are involved**

images.dart:

```
part of 'resources.dart';

class AppImages {
  AppImages._();

  static const String moviePlacholder = 'assets/images/movie_placholder.jpg';
}
```

spider.yaml:

```
# Generated by Spider
# For more info on configuration, visit https://birjuvachhani.github.io/spider/grouping/  
# Generates unit tests to verify that the assets exists in assets directory
generate_tests: false

# Use this to remove vcs noise created by the `generated` comments in dart code
no_comments: true

# Exports all the generated file as the one library
export: true

# This allows you to import all the generated references with 1 single import!
use_part_of: true

# Generates a variable that contains a list of all asset values.
use_references_list: false

# Generates files with given ignore rules for file.
# ignored_rules:
#   - public_member_api_docs

# Generates dart font family references for fonts specified in pubspec.yaml
# fonts: true
# -------- OR --------
# fonts:
#   class_name: MyFonts
#   file_name: my_fonts

# Location where all the generated references will be stored
package: resources

groups:
  - path: assets/images
    class_name: AppImages
    types: [ .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .webp, .webm, .bmp ]
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: the_movie_db
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.0-146.2.beta <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg : ^1.1.6


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.3.0
  flip_card: ^0.6.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
    - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
fonts:
    - family: GrapeNuts
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/GrapeNuts-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

main.dart:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_movie_db/Theme/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:the_movie_db/widgets/auth/auth_widget.dart';
import 'package:the_movie_db/widgets/main_screen/main_screen_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: false,
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 145, 145, 145),
            backgroundColor: AppColors.mainDarkBlue,
          ),
          bottomNavigationBarTheme: const BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
              backgroundColor: AppColors.mainDarkBlue,
              selectedItemColor: AppColors.mainLightBlue),
          unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey),
      routes: {
        '/auth': (context) => const AuthWidget(),
        '/main_screen': (context) => const MainScreenWidget()
      },
      initialRoute: '/auth',
    );
  }
}
```

movie_list_widget.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../resources/resources.dart';

class MovieListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MovieListWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MovieListWidget> createState() => _MovieListWidgetState();
}

class _MovieListWidgetState extends State<MovieListWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemExtent: 163,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Row(
              children: const [
                Image(image: AssetImage(AppImages.moviePlacholder))
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

[image: error screen looks like this]

**there are no errors in the code, but the crane does not display the image from the assets/mages folder**

[image: console gives the following errors]

Comment: completely, Stop the app and uninstall from the emulator and run it again.

Comment: I completely closed the browser and started the application again several times, but it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, Just to keep a clear conscience, try very good old

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter pub get
```

By the way, when i look at your error message, the second blue line says  that your path is

```
assets/assets/images/movie_placholder.jpg
```

I mean, something with your path is very wrong, since it's calling the folder "assets" inside another one, OR, the package automatically search and adds the "/assets" for you, so when you add it, it concatenate and give you the wrong path.

So probably your class **AppImages** should be

```
part of 'resources.dart';

class AppImages {
  AppImages._();

  static const String moviePlacholder = '/images/movie_placholder.jpg'; 
  // If this doesn't work try this one instead:
  // static const String moviePlacholder = 'images/movie_placholder.jpg';
}
```

Hope it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simple solution but - did You stop and restart the app after adding assets?

I had the same problem, and it was happening because of hot restart/reload.

Comment: I completely closed the browser and started the application again several times, but it did not help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your asset path in your pubspec.yaml is wrong

Change

```
- images/
```

to

```
- assets/images/
```

Comment: I already fixed it but it didn't help